# Using Query Builder Methods against DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext, query-builder, objectquery

I would like to use the "[Query Builder Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb896238%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)" on my `DbContext` like following:

```
using (var context = new MyDbContext())
{
    var query = context.MyEntities.Where("Id = @id", new ObjectParameter("id", 1));
}
```

But it cannot resolve this specific overload of `Where`. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using this solved my problem:

```
var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter) context).ObjectContext;
var query = objectContext.CreateObjectSet<MyEntities>().Where("it.Id = @id", new ObjectParameter("id", 1));
```

Comment: It doesn't have to be that hard: `context.MyEntities.Where(x=>x.Id == 1);`

Comment: I am aware of that of course, just trying to build dynamic queries.